# How to store json object in a variable using apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

The following flowfile is the response of an ***"InvokeHttp"***:

```
[
{"data1":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"},
{"data2":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"},
{"data3":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}
]
```

I did a ***"SplitJson"***, i got each json record as a single flowfile

flowfile 1:

```
{"data1":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}
```

flowfile 2:

```
{"data2":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}
```

flowfile 3:

```
{"data3":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}
```

I want to store each json record in each flowfile in a variable like that:

```
variable1 = "{"data1":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}"
variable2 = "{"data2":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}"
variable3 = "{"data3":"[{....},{...},{....}]","info":"data-from_site"}"
```

***can someone show me how to store the json record in a variable !***

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do (by "variable", do you mean what is called "attribute" in NiFi?), you can use the EvaluateJsonPath processor configured with:

- flowfile-attribute as Destination
- json as Return type